# Splitting Artist Names from One Column

Tags: python, pandas, split

I am pulling data from the billboard 100 list and am stuck on how to split the artists names.  This is a csv file, but I have the data in a pandas dataframe before export. I would like to split using python/pandas. I have included a picture of the column below. The artist names are all in the same column with delimiters (in red) I would like to split but it is very complicated. The most common delimiters are " & ", " Featuring ", " X ", so basically I need help on splitting all of these names into different columns.

[image]

I was thinking I could use nested for loops so that I could split on a combination of these delimiters. My idea was to split based on a pattern of " (symbol) ", " X ", " x ", and " Featuring ", but am not sure if this is possible. Is there an easier way to do this without losing data? All help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, please [edit] your question to include any relevant data as text in your question. Thanks.

Comment: Did you conider Perl Regular Expresions?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a sample dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'singers': ['A & B', 'C Featuring D', 'E X F', 'G % H']})
df
    singers
0   A & B
1   C Featuring D
2   E X F
3   G % H
```

Now, it's up to you which delimiter you want to choose to split the names on. May be just `X` or just `Featuring` or `&` or maybe all of them. Use `str.split` to achieve this as shown -

```
df.singers.str.split('&|X|Featuring|%', expand=True)
    0   1
0   A   B
1   C   D
2   E   F
3   G   H
```

You can even add any other symbol too inside the split method.